# Why is Vs 36 Volts?

Tags: dc, current-source, series, voltage-source

Stumped by this seemingly simple circuit. Why is the voltage across the current source 36 volts and not 24 volts? Please explain step by step if possible, **thanks**.

[image]

(I solved it with an MIT circuit solver and it said that the voltage across is 36v):
[image]

Comment: What makes you think the voltage across the current source should be 24V? You can't just ignore the 12V source. It's there. It affects things. The current source has to overcome that too. In your mind, what voltage is developed across the resistor?

Comment: R1 should dissipate 24 volts because V=IR so 24v = 0.008A*3000Ohms.

Comment: Right. So what happen if you stick the 12V source between it and ground??

Comment: 12 volts opposes the voltage that dropped by 24 bringing the other side down to zero volts.

Comment: No. Look closer. The source voltage polarity and R1 voltage drop polarity are not in opposing directions. Current can flow backwards through a voltage source by the way if something else in the circuit can overpower it.

Comment: I thought voltages opposed each other if along the path it goes through it from the positive to the negative terminal.

Comment: No. I know what you were told that makes you think that but you don't understand wqhat it is trying to say. It's that when *following the current*, Vdrop is positive when going + to -, and negative when going - to +. Passive sign convention. So follow the current direction. First we start at resistor and go + to - so we have 24V drop. Then we go through voltage source + to - which is another 12V drop. Total 36V.

Comment: Pay attention to the direction of the voltage drop in R caused by the current source. You can't just ignore the polarity of the resistor voltage drop and assume the resistor voltage drop will oppose the voltage source. You actually have to look at it. For the resistor voltage drop, is + and - on the left or right of the resistor?

Comment: The positive terminal would be on the right side of the resistor because the current is flowing up from the right correct?

Comment: Yes, current enters the resistor on the right so the voltage drop polarity is positive on the right, negative on the left.

Comment: So basically because we know that it dropped by -24v from the resistor and then -12v from the voltage source (to get to zero/ground) then the original voltage from the current source must have been 36v?

Comment: Your wording is a bit weird but yes.

Comment: The task is kind of weird and artificial because current will only flow in case the 8mA current source has higher voltage potential than the battery. If it's a 12V voltage source that can deliver 8mA then the voltage across the resistor is 0V...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, due to the current source, the current flowing in the the circuit is 8mA.
Now apply KVL to the loop.

We get voltage across the loop as
12V + (3kohm x 8mA) = Vs .. Here, voltage increases due to current direction through the
resistor.
So,
Vs = 12 + 24 = 36V

Answer (score -3):

Current in the resistor is because of both the voltage and current source. Convert the voltage source into the equivalent current source. 12/3000 = 0.004 Ampere in parallel  with 3000 ohm is the equivalent current source for the voltage source (12v in series with 3000 ohm resistor).

Now we have two parallel current sources with the resistor. 0.004+0.008 = 0.012 is the total current flowing in the 3000 ohm resistor.

And 0.012*3000 = 36 volts is the voltage across the resistor.

Comment: _"Current in the resistor is because of both the voltage and current source"_- No, it's solely determined by the current source. Perhaps you meant to say something else?

Comment: This isn't correct. There are several things incorrect. The first is that voltage polarity of the two sources oppose each other and your math has them assisting each other. But this is moot because the current source determines the current in this circuit since all current in the circuit flows through it. The only reason you end up with the same magnitude is due to a coincidence in component values.